# Алгоритм построения древа каталога

Tags: алгоритм, php

В базе данных есть таблица хранящая список категорий

**id   parentID     название**
1       0               Категория 1
2       0               Категория 2
3       2               Категория 3
4       2               Категория 4

Нужно придумать алгоритм на php который бы переводил эту конструкцию во что-то подобное:

1. Категория 1
2. категория 2
    2.1 Категория 3
    2.2 Категория 4

Comment: Переведите в html в xml, потом в многомерный массив.

Comment: не понимаю зачем xml?
ваш комментарий навел меня на мысль использования динамического многомерного массива, но у меня все так же нет идей как это дело правильно считать из БД (MySQL)

Comment: вам нужна функция, которая будет проходить по массиву и находить для каждого элемента родителя (если parentID != 0) и записывать этот элемент в дети родителя (по ссылке), после чего будет удалять все элементы массива, у которых parentID != 0. В результате у вас останутся только те деревья, чьи корни действительно являются корневыми элементами искомого дерева. Если будет время, позже напишу пример.

Comment: основную суть алгоритма я представляю так:  
берем строку  
если родитель == 0 $array[id]=$name;  
иначе  
$array[parentID][]=$name;  
берем следующую строку и все заново. Логично?

Comment: У Вас сначала была ДОМ модель в табличной вёрстке, если нужно с базы, то ниже вам уже подсказали.

Comment: Как вам такая реализация? 
    foreach ($sql as $row)
    {
        if ($row['parentID']==0)
            $array[$row['id']]=$row['name'];
        else
            $array[$row['parentID']][]=$row['name'];
    }

Comment: @undestroyer, у вас оригинальные значения быстро затрутся. Под ключами будут либо полноценные записи, либо массивы детей, и дальше одного уровня не пойдет.

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 6):

**Таблица в базе данных:**

```
+--+-------------+--------+
|id|name         |parentid|
+--+-------------+--------+
|1 |Имя раздела 1|0       |
|2 |Имя раздела 2|0       |
|3 |Имя раздела 3|1       |
|4 |Имя раздела 4|2       |
|5 |Имя раздела 5|4       |
|6 |Имя раздела 6|2       |
+--+-------------+--------+
```

**Массив, полученный после выборки из базы данных:**

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Имя раздела 1',
        'parentid' => '0'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'Имя раздела 2',
        'parentid' => '0'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '3',
        'name' => 'Имя раздела 3',
        'parentid' => '1'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '4',
        'name' => 'Имя раздела 4',
        'parentid' => '2'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '5',
        'name' => 'Имя раздела 5',
        'parentid' => '4'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '6',
        'name' => 'Имя раздела 6',
        'parentid' => '2'
    ),
);
```

**Функции, для рекурсивного построения дерева:**

```
function form_tree($mess)
{
    if (!is_array($mess)) {
        return false;
    }
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($mess as $value) {
        $tree[$value['parentid']][] = $value;
    }
    return $tree;
}

//$parent_id - какой parentid считать корневым
//по умолчанию 0 (корень)
function build_tree($cats, $parent_id)
{
    if (is_array($cats) && isset($cats[$parent_id])) {
        $tree = '<ul>';
        foreach ($cats[$parent_id] as $cat) {
            $tree .= '<li>' . $cat['name'];
            $tree .= build_tree($cats, $cat['id']);
            $tree .= '</li>';
        }
        $tree .= '</ul>';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

**Примеры использования**
**Вариант А:**

```
$tree = form_tree($arr);
echo build_tree($tree, 0);
```

- Имя раздела 1

  - Имя раздела 3
- Имя раздела 2

  - Имя раздела 4

    - Имя раздела 5
  - Имя раздела 6

**Вариант Б:**

```
$tree = form_tree($arr);
echo build_tree($tree, 2);
```

- Имя раздела 4

  - Имя раздела 5
- Имя раздела 6

---

#### Как работает алгоритм

Исходный массив обрабатывается функцией `form_tree();`.
Она формирует массив следующего вида:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(        
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Имя раздела 1',
            'parentid' => '0'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '2',
            'name' => 'Имя раздела 2',
            'parentid' => '0'
        ),
    ),
    1 => array(
        array(
            'id' => '3',
            'name' => 'Имя раздела 3',
            'parentid' => '1'
        ),
    ),
    2 => array(
        array(
            'id' => '4',
            'name' => 'Имя раздела 4',
            'parentid' => '2'
        ),        
        array(
            'id' => '6',
            'name' => 'Имя раздела 6',
            'parentid' => '2'
        ),
    ),
    4 => array(
        array(
            'id' => '5',
            'name' => 'Имя раздела 5',
            'parentid' => '4'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Как можно видеть, элементы исходного массива были разбиты на группы, согласно их родителю. В итоге получилась схема вида: `родитель => массив потомков`.

Далее, функция `build_tree()` рекурсивно обрабатывает этот массив.
Она начинает свою работу с ID раздела, указанного в качестве корневого.
В первую очередь, она стремится перебрать потомков данного раздела. В процессе перебора функция проверяет, а не является ли текущий потомок в свою очередь чьим-то родителем? Для этого функция вызывает саму себя, с указанием в качестве ID корневого раздела ID текущего элемента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Рассмотрим работу алгоритма на примере "Вариант А"**:

- Мы начинаем перебор с `ID = 0`, в качестве корневого.
- Первый раздел, который мы встречаем во время перебора, это `Имя раздела 1`.
- Выводим этот раздел.

  - Начинаем перебор с `ID = 1`, в качестве корневого.
  - Первый раздел, который мы встречаем во время перебора, это `Имя раздела 3`.
  - Выводим этот раздел.

    - Мы начинаем перебор с `ID = 3`, в качестве корневого.
    - Подразделов нет, функция завершает свою работу.
  - Разделов больше нет, функция завершает свою работу.
- Продолжаем перебор с `ID = 0`, в качестве корневого.
- Второй раздел, который мы встречаем во время перебора, это `Имя раздела 2`.
- Выводим этот раздел.

  - Начинаем перебор с `ID = 2`, в качестве корневого.
  - Первый раздел, который мы встречаем во время перебора, это `Имя раздела 4`.
  - Выводим этот раздел.

    - Мы начинаем перебор с `ID = 4`, в качестве корневого.
    - Первый раздел, который мы встречаем во время перебора, это `Имя раздела 5`.
    - Выводим этот раздел.
        •  Мы начинаем перебор с `ID = 5`, в качестве корневого.
        •  Подразделов нет, функция завершает свою работу.
    - Разделов больше нет, функция завершает свою работу.
  - Второй раздел, который мы встречаем во время перебора, это `Имя раздела 6`.
  - Выводим этот раздел.

    - Мы начинаем перебор с `ID = 6`, в качестве корневого.
    - Подразделов нет, функция завершает свою работу.
  - Разделов больше нет, функция завершает свою работу.
- Разделов больше нет, функция завершает свою работу.

---

В примере выше, уровень вложенности соответствует тому, в который раз по счету функция `build_tree()` вызвала сама себя.

Comment: а как работает данный алгоритм?

Comment: @upward, добавил подробное описание работы алгоритма

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите на `php` алгоритм. то делайте так например:

1. Пишем функцию, которая будет принимать 1 параметр на вход  Ид родителя. Для каждого полученного значения она вызывает сама себя и передеает себе ИД только что полученного значения.

**Например:**

```
function get_tree($in=0,$array){
// $xx= mysql_query("select * from tree WHERE parent=$in")
  $tt = mysql_fetch_array($xx){
    $array[$ur][$tt[id]] = $tt['name'];
    get_tree($tt['id'],$array)
    }
}
```

Думаю суть понятна. Код привел для примера, писал его прям тут.  На выходе вы поулчим массив с уровнями

Comment: Рекурсивные походы в базу. Не надо так.